# Manually Close native screen picker of getDisplayMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediadevices, get-display-media

Could I possibly close the native screen picker of getDisplayMedia({video:true}) without selecting an application to share?
As far as I know, it automatically closes on track.stop() if a track being shared is stopped. However, there is an instance that I need to close the native screen picker without pressing cancel or selecting an application to share.

[image: Screen Picker Img]

Answer (score 2):

Refresh the page:

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

This will tear down this otherwise sticky prompt in all browsers.

In Chrome, the prompt is modal, but this [demo using a timeout](https://jan-ivar.github.io/dummy/gdm_timeout.html) works for me:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

button.onclick = async () => {
  const stream = await Promise.race([
    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true}),
    wait(5000)
  ]);
  if (!stream) {
    window.location = window.location.href;
  }
  video.srcObject = stream;
```

Of course, this risks tearing away the picker while the user is using it.

Comment: This is actually helpful. But sadly in our case, we need to close the picker without having to reload the page. I was thinking if there was an event to be fired for this but I can't find anything on its documentation.

Comment: @TheChosenOne Is it an option to put the request in an iframe? Then you'd only need to refresh that iframe, not your whole page.